# save image/video to gallery in IOS using cordova flle transfer

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am downloading images/videos from an application created by me in Cordova iOS. I want to access the downloaded files from other applications too, like WhatsApp, Instagram, Telegram etc.

I am able to download files, but am unable to view them in gallery or videos, unable to access filesystem root path in iOS.

Do we have any plugins in Cordova for iOS for moving files from documents directory to camera roll? if not, can you guide me how to achieve it by following the native C process as I am new to C.

Here is my sample code which is working in iOS.

```js
var url = encodeURI("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"); // image url
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
    //cordova.file.documentsDirectory
    //cordova.file.dataDirectory
    //fs.root.fullPath
    //rootdir.toURL();
    //fileSystem.root
    alert("the root is" + cordova.file.documentsDirectory)
    var imagePath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "/big_buck_bunny.mp4";
    alert(imagePath);
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(url, imagePath, function(entry, imagePath) {
        alert(imagePath);
        console.log(imagePath);
        alert(entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
        // download();
        downloadFile();
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Some error");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the cordova-plugin-filetransfer. You may want to check https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-camera-roll to save a base 64 encoded image to the camera roll. There's a fork for working with videos, but encoding a big video in base 64 is probably not very efficient.